# straightforward bitmap memory leak

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, bitmap

I'm writing a routine to convert various types of images to PNG format. No saving for later, just read in, write out. As far as I can tell, I am disposing everything I can.  Here is the relevant code:

```
            lock (mLocker)
            {
                startAvail = MemoryLog(LogLevel.Info, "ExtractI", "aOrig='" + aOrigImageName + "' got the lock");

                System.Drawing.Bitmap b;
                b = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(aFileName);
                string outfile = Path.Combine(mDocumentImageDir, aModImageName);
                b.Save(outfile, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                b.Dispose();

                MemoryLog(LogLevel.Info, "ExtractI", "aOrig='" + aOrigImageName + "' calling collect");
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

                endAvail = MemoryLog(LogLevel.Info, "ExtractI", "aOrig='" + aOrigImageName + "' releasing lock");
                logger.Info("Diff: "+ (endAvail - startAvail)+"\r\n");
            }
```

Key lines in MemoryLog() are:

```
        using (PerformanceCounter perfCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available Bytes"))
        {
            long availableMemory = Convert.ToInt64(perfCounter.NextValue());
            return availableMemory;
        }
```

I call this routine for a series of images, and here is the output:

2015-11-20 11:22:00.793|Info| ExtractI   (image1): avail=10971725824, priv=0, aOrig='image1.emf' got the lock

2015-11-20 11:22:00.913|Info| ExtractI   (image1): avail=10970079232, priv=0, aOrig='image1.emf' calling collect

2015-11-20 11:22:00.913|Info| ExtractI   (image1): avail=10970034176, priv=0, aOrig='image1.emf' releasing lock

2015-11-20 11:22:00.913|Info|Diff: -1691648

2015-11-20 11:22:00.943|Info| ExtractI  (image10): avail=10970124288, priv=0, aOrig='image10.emf' got the lock

2015-11-20 11:22:00.973|Info| ExtractI  (image10): avail=10969792512, priv=0, aOrig='image10.emf' calling collect

2015-11-20 11:22:00.973|Info| ExtractI  (image10): avail=10966958080, priv=0, aOrig='image10.emf' releasing lock

2015-11-20 11:22:00.973|Info|Diff: -3166208

2015-11-20 11:22:00.993|Info| ExtractI  (image11): avail=10966966272, priv=0, aOrig='image11.emf' got the lock

2015-11-20 11:22:01.083|Info| ExtractI  (image11): avail=10965856256, priv=0, aOrig='image11.emf' calling collect

2015-11-20 11:22:01.083|Info| ExtractI  (image11): avail=10966171648, priv=0, aOrig='image11.emf' releasing lock

2015-11-20 11:22:01.083|Info|Diff: -794624

Memory is still dropping and the "new Bitmap()" hangs if a large image is near the end instead of near the beginning. I appreciate any help given, this doesn't seem to be the usual "you need to call dispose" problem.

Comment: [MSDN How to: Convert Images from One Format to Another](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twss4wb0(v=vs.90).aspx) have you looked at the documentation here.. not sure why you are taking the long approach

Comment: I wouldn't call the GC.Collect if any of your objects have finalisers they are likely to be moved to next generation if the finaliser haven't run yet.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. The GC call and various memory log operations were just added to debugging. Using Image instead of Bitmap produced the same results. I found an odd answer to this, a small msdn reference concerning EMF file type:

Comment: Classes within the System.Drawing.Imaging namespace are not supported for use within a Windows or ASP.NET service. Attempting to use these classes from within one of these application types may produce unexpected problems, such as diminished service performance and run-time exceptions.